# API to make youtube full screen on chromecast

Tags: iframe, youtube, chromecast

Can the Chromecast browser allow the iframe Youtube player to be set into full screen mode.  Want to use this for a screen saver mode.  Normally player not full screen, but if no sessions are doing anything then I want to take it to full screen while the playlist is playing.

I do not want to start it up in full screen, I want to switch to full screen after 3 minutes of inactivity on the chromecast receiver.

Comment: did you find a way to achieve this?